# Issue with a middleware on deployment

Tags: reactjs, typescript, middleware

I have a create react app, and I want to include a middleware in it. The reason for this inclusion is the call to an external API that I don't have control over. When I use my middleware locally everything goes fine my API calls go through, and they return the correct data. But when I deploy on platform sh, they don't go through anymore and it returns a 405 error as if the middleware is not effective. Here is what my middleware looks like, it is very simple:

proxy.ts

```
import { createProxyMiddleware } from "http-proxy-middleware";

export default function (app: any) {
  app.use(
    "/api",
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: "https://api.mews-demo.com",
      changeOrigin: true,
      pathRewrite: {
        "^/api": "",
      },
    })
  );
}
```

And this file is in src of my React project.